# C# How to check which part of an if statement is correct

Tags: c#, if-statement

i wonder how can you check which part of a if statement was the correct one. For example if you have this :

```
int a = 1, b, c, d;
    if(a > 0 || b > 1 || c > 2 || d > 3)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Now in this case the one that made the if correct is `a`. So how can you verify this ?
Basically you can put them in 4 different if's but if you have to do a repetitive code for each one you can probably come up with some method for it but isn't there actually a way to pass some value for example ?

Comment: If you have repetitive code in each branch, do what we usually do when faced with repetitive code: refactor it out into a method.

Comment: yea i thought you can do that but i really would like to see some way of checking which part of the if is correct ..

Comment: us the debugger and click QuickWatch and paste in the variables you want to compare or use the command window

Comment: @kopelence: The way is to split the `if` expression into multiple `if`/`elseif`.

Comment: Yea i guess i will be back to refactoring the code inside and using 4 separated if's .. I was curious if there's such a thing :P let's say `var a = if.result.item1` haha

Comment: When you have that much conditions its better to outsource them in variables like `var aIsBiggerThanZero = a > 0;` and then in your if you have `ìf(aIsBiggerThanZero || ...)`. Then you can easily find out for example in debug mode which of them is true. And you code is cleaner because the variables are explaining what's checked in the condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One approach in situations when you need to know not only the overall result, but also the item that made the result `true`, is to put conditionals into an array, and perform the chain of ORs `||`s yourself:

```
var conditions = new[] {a > 0, b > 1, c > 2, d > 3};
var whichOne = Array.IndexOf(conditions, true);
if (whichOne >= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("Condition number {0} is true", whichOne);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("The condition is false");
}
```

Note that this approach is different from the `||` chain in that it does not *short circuit* the evaluation. In other words, all four conditions would be evaluated before the call to `IndexOf`.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for ,thanks !

Comment: One important side effect of this, it does remove the short-circuiting behavior of `&&` and `||`. Not normally a big deal, but can be a issue for stuff like `if (x != null && x.SomeVal > 2)`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's exactly what the last two sentences of the answer are saying :-)

Comment: I was going to post a similar answer, great! ;D

Comment: If you want to convolute it, you could make those conditions `Func<bool>`, then you could short-circuit aswell :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way in C# to accomplish this. It's evaluated in the if, then the result is essentially thrown away.

You can either run the test again:

```
int a = 1, b, c, d;

if(a > 0 || b > 1 || c > 2 || d > 3)
{
    if(a > 0)
    {
        // do special stuff
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

Or if it's expensive, store it separately:

```
int a = 1, b, c, d;
bool aOverZero = a > 0;

if(aOverZero || b > 1 || c > 2 || d > 3)
{
    if(aOverZero)
    {
        // do special stuff
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

Or just use another method for the repeated code:

```
int a = 1, b, c, d;

if(a > 0)
{
    // do special stuff
    doStuff();
}
else if (b > 1)
{
    // do special stuff
    doStuff();
}
```

Which you pick just depends on what your code is, how expensive the tests are to run, and what makes it the most readable. In this case, where it's clearly exaggerated how simple it is, readability will be the top concern. I'd probably default to the first one. Introducing a whole other variable in-scope probably isn't worth it.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to handle this is to [refactor the conditional to a polymorphic object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) ([better example](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)). You refactor `doStuff()` out to a parent object, then give each variable its own object. You call `doStuff()` on your object and it completely removes the conditional. Your object gets instantiated based on the values of the variable that you were testing. The primary benefit of this is that you can implement `doStuff()` once and have each of the child objects do whatever special behavior you need them to do before they call `super()`.