# C# checking what condition was met in if statement with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, exception, conditional-statements

I am checking for an error exception if some inputs are greater than 7 or smaller than 0:

```
if (number1 > 7 || number1 < 0 || number2 > 7 || number2 < 0){
  throw new Exception("Invalid position <pos>");
}
catch (Exception e){
  Console.Write(e)
}
```

how can I print what number was the error? E.g: number1 is 10 but number2 is 3, i want to print "Invalid position <10>"

Comment: `throw new Exception($"Invalid position {number1}");`?

Comment: That would print number1 even if number2 was the one wrong. I want to know if it's possible to check what condition is met in the if statement without using many if/elseif statements.

Comment: Split one `if` into two ones: for `number1` and for `number2`.

Comment: So there's no way to check the fulfilled condition on an if statement?

Comment: And... use `nameof` rather than a literal name like `"number1"`. If those numbers are function parameters, use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: What happens if number1 = 11 and number2 = 12? If that is a possibility you can't use if and else if.

Comment: @Ignacio perhaps tell us a bit more about the context of your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# How to check which part of an if statement is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685882/c-sharp-how-to-check-which-part-of-an-if-statement-is-correct)

Comment: Agree with @sommmen. There may be a better way to pare down your code. As it is, there isn't a simple way to use a single if statement to display the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if it's possible to check what condition is met in the if statement without using many if/elseif statements.

There is no such way, you'd have to split your if.

```cs
if (number1 > 7 || number1 < 0 ){
  throw new Exception($"Invalid position <{number1}>");
}
elseif(number2 > 7 || number2 < 0) {
  throw new Exception($"Invalid position <{number2}>");
}
catch (Exception e){
  Console.Write(e)
}
```

Comment: What happens if number1 = 11 and number2 = 12? If that is a possibility you can't use if and else if.

Comment: Well an exception gets thrown for number1 - exactly what the original behaviour was i suppose. What would you'd like to see here an aggregateexception for both values?

Comment: (see discussion with Dmitry Bychenko)

Answer (score 0):

If `number1` and `number2` are *arguments*, you can just *validate* them separatedly:

```
// if number1 and number2 are input parameters, we just validate them: 
if (number1 < 0 || number1 > 7)
  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(number1), "Invalid position <pos>");
if (number2 < 0 || number2 > 7)
  throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(number2), "Invalid position <pos>");
```

If `number1` and `number2` are some kind of settings, you can exploit the same idea:

```
// If number1 and number2 are local variables, we have some inner problems
// in the routine. That's why I vote for - InvalidOperationException -
// something when wrong
if (number1 < 0 || number1 > 7)
  throw new InvalidOperationException(
    $"Invalid position <pos>, {nameof(number1)} = {number1} is out of [0..7] range.");
if (number2 < 0 || number2 > 7)
  throw new InvalidOperationException(
    $"Invalid position <pos>, {nameof(number2)} = {number2} is out of [0..7] range.");
```

Please note, that throwing as well as catching (*swallowing*) `Exception` is often a *bad practice*: your code should deal with an *easy case only* when `number1` or `number2` are out of range and not with *all possible exceptional situations*.

If you want to write some *warning* and keep on doing, you can get rid of exception throwing at all:

```
if (number1 > 7 || number1 < 0)
  Console.Write($"Invalid position <pos>: {nameof(number1)} is out of range");
else if (number2 > 7 || number2 < 0)
  Console.Write($"Invalid position <pos>: {nameof(number2)} is out of range");
else {
  // Both number1 and number2 are valid
}
```

Comment: Not sure that throwing multiple exceptions is the best idea. Possibly hold a value to display in one exception?

Comment: @OldDog: each *exceptional* situation should be, IMHO, separated from one another (since they are *exceptional*). Actually, at most one exception will be thrown

Comment: you have a point about multiple exceptions. But if the exceptions are similar and part of the same comparatives, I would normally rather throw one and list them, rather than making the user have to see 2 and close 2 separate windows. But as stated in the comments, if number1 = 11 and number2 = 12 there will be two exceptions.

Comment: @OldDog: there'll be just *one exception thrown*: if, say, `number1 = -123` then exception will be thrown, *execution will be broken* and it'll be continued at `catch` block. technically, you can change second `if` into `else if` but it doesn't change the flow

Comment: Good point. But once execution is broken, either the second is missed or you have to catch it elsewhere, which would mean essentially another exception? No worries, answer was accepted. Anyway, I enjoyed the discussion. :-)

Comment: @OldDog: the second (as well as the third if any) is missed (*skipped*): validation has failed, that's enough for us to stop normal flow and go to `catch`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to split this if statement up into a func:

```
Func<int,int,int,bool> InRange= (number,low,high) =>
{
  if(number>high || number<low)
      return false;
  return true;
}

if(!InRange(number1,0,7))
  throw new Exception($"Invalid position <{number1}>");
if(!InRange(number2,0,7))
  throw new Exception($"Invalid position <{number2}>");
```

Really though in cases like theses your numbers should be in some sort of list so it would be more like:

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
  if(!InRange(number,0,7))
     throw new Exception($"Invalid position <{number}>");
```

Also you should not use hard coded number like 0 and 7. They should either be inputs or set to constants

Comment: The easiest? Really? :)

Comment: This seems like overkill - for a new contributor though, you have a nicely formatted post. Welcome.

Comment: hahah yeah might be a bit overkill but was the first thing that came to my mind and I like reusability :P

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, with a single `throw`, contrary to the other solutions:

```cs
if (number1 > 7 || number1 < 0 || number2 > 7 || number2 < 0)
{
    var invalidNumbers = new List<string>();
    if(number1 > 7 || number1 < 0)
    {
        invalidNumbers.Add($"{number1}");
    }
    if (number2 > 7 || number2 < 0)
    {
        invalidNumbers.Add($"{number2}");
    }
    throw new Exception($"Invalid position {string.Join(", ",invalidNumbers)}");
}
```

If `number1`, or `number2`, or both `number1` and `number2` are wrong, you are notified via one unique exception.

If your condition is the same for every numbers, as you might imply:

> if some inputs are greater than 7 or smaller than 0

you can generalize easily and have a more elegant code using Linq:

```cs
var number1 = 8;
var number2 = -1;

var numbers = new List<int>
{
    number1,
    number2
    // Add as many numbers as you wish.
};

var wrongNumbers = numbers
    .Where(n => n > 7 || n < 0) // The condition to apply to all numbers.
    .ToList();
    
if(wrongNumbers.Any())
{
    var wrongNumbersAsString = string.Join(", ", wrongNumbers
        .Select(n => $"{n}"));

    throw new Exception($"wrong numbers: {wrongNumbersAsString}");
}
```